# Android loading different versions of database when using "back" vs "up" navigation

Tags: android, database, sqlite, navigation

**SOLVED:** The problem was with my implementation. I thought saveAll() was an empty method that I never implemented, but I actually did, and within it was saving old data.

I'm trying to make an app with a pretty standard design. The user is presented with a list of items. When they select one, it goes to a new activity with more information about that item. They edit that data, it automatically saves to the database, and they go back to the list. However, the method with which they go back to the list changes the data displayed. When using the "back" button, it loads the correct, current version of the database. When using the "up" button in the action bar, it loads the previous version of the database.

I have narrowed the cause of this down to one key difference: when pressing the "up" button, an activity's `onCreate()` method is called, while when pressing the "back" button, an activity's `onResume()` method is called. I have created a function to reload the list of items from the database, and call it in both methods. However, it only gets the current version of the database from `onResume()`, when using the "back" button to return to the list activity.

To access the database, I have a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and within it a method to get a singleton instance of said class, as shown below.

```
private static DBHelper singletonInstance;
    public static synchronized DBHelper getSingletonInstance (Context context) {
    if (singletonInstance == null) {
        singletonInstance = new DBHelper(context);
    }
    return singletonInstance;
}
```

As far as I know, this means it would be impossible for a problem like this to ever occur. Yet it does. I have tried numerous solutions and am lost at what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is my implementation of `onOptionsItemSelected()`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        ...
        case android.R.id.home:
            saveAll();
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        ...
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I'm new to android development, so I got this from another StackOverflow post,  and it's the only way I've tried navigating up. Data is not saved here, as I automatically save data from the `EditText` fields after a small delay, using a custom subclass of `TextWatcher`. I know it works, because when I use the "back" button and then select the same item in the list, the new data appears.

**EDIT 2:** Here are my `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("onCreate called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_glaze_list);
    dbLoader.execute("");
    ...
}

...

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("called on resume");
    if (dbHelper != null) {
        populateList();
    }
    else System.out.println("dbHelper has not been initialized");
}
```

`dbLoader` is an `AsyncTask` I created to make sure the list is populated only after the database is loaded. It's implementation is shown below. I have tried loading the database and populating the list without the `AsyncTask`, but I still run into the same problem.

```
public class DbLoader extends AsyncTask<String,Void,DBHelper> {
    protected DBHelper doInBackground(String... params) {
        return DBHelper.getSingletonInstance(getApplicationContext());
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(DBHelper result) {
        dbHelper = result;
        populateList();
    }

}
```

You can see I have included some breakpoints with the prints to tell me what's going on. What I've found is when I press the "up" button (i.e. when `onCreate()` is called), `dbHelper`, my subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`, is not initialized. However, when pressing the "back" button (i.e. when `onResume()` is called), `dbHelper` is already initialized. I think this is where the problem lies. Somehow, in re-instantiating `dbHelper`, it loads an older version of the database. I have no idea why this would occur.

Comment: Can you show the method where you are handling your `up` button? i.e the `onOptionsItemSelected` method in your activity?

Comment: I've added my implementation of said method, and included some other details about how I save text.

Comment: What happens if you replace `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` by `this.finish()`? If it doesn't help, please shoe `onResume` and `onCreate` as well.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri using `this.finish()` did not solve the problem. I also tried using `finishFromChild()`, and this did nothing as well. I have included some additional information in my post that may help.